# asus eee top: Sound control buttons stopped working after I've installed windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is there any specific driver I need to install to fix them?

It's not clear why they are not working. E.g. display contrast buttons placed near sound buttons work fine.

Comment: Did you check the Asus website for W7 drivers?

Comment: The issue is that I can't understand how to find anything on their site.... The interface is really hard to explore..

Comment: I agree, one reason I have never owned an Asus PC. What is the specific model number?

Comment: Start on this page, click download, the use the automatic detection feature....http://support.asus.com/ServiceHome.aspx?SLanguage=en